# Prove that proposition is true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How can I prove that:

$C\subset A$, if and only if (A $\cap$ B) $\cup$ C = A $\cap$ (B $\cup$ C)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That should be $C \subseteq A$

Comment: So in my question is the proposition false?

Comment: The $\subset$ is usually understood as the *strict* subset, meaning that there is at least one element in $A$ that is not in $C$ ... and with $A=B=C$ then  $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap(B \cup C$, but we would not have that $C \subset A$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

First prove:

$C \subseteq A$ iff $A \cup C = A$

Answer (score 0):

Let $C\subseteq A$ then we know that $A\cap C = C$. This fact will be used in the following equation:
$$(A\cap B) \cup C = (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = A \cap (B \cup C).$$
The last equation was the result of the distributive law.

If $(A\cap B) \cup C= A \cap (B \cup C)$ and $C \not \subseteq A$ then there is an $x\in C$ which is not in $A$. Clearly this $x\in C$ is also in $(A\cap B) \cup C$ but it cannot be in the right-hand-side $A \cap (B \cup C)$ since the right-hand-side is a subset of $A$ which gives us the contradiction.